# Using 256 color on screen's status line

Tags: gnu-screen

How can I use a color from 256-color template for screen's status bar items (hardstatus setting in .screenrc)? The screen manual (STRING ESCAPES section) only lists 10 colors to use for the status line.

Comment: Screen by default only supports 8 bit colors, there's a batch that extends the color support to 256. But you should try tmux it supports 256 colors and, in my opinion, a superior alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify with `termcapinfo` command.  Place the following code in your `~/.screenrc`:

```
termcapinfo xterm 'Co#256:AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm'
```

This worked with

- screen 4.1.0~201203
- on Debian unstable amd64
- with putty 0.61 on Windows, and
- TERM is `screen`.

Someone says that you need more setting according to you setup. [This blog post](http://www.tigraine.at/2012/01/25/make-gnu-screen-xterm-256color-work-on-osx/) seems to be informative.

Hope this helps